# Polymer core-drawer-panel throws exception at loading

Tags: java, dom, gwt, polymer, gwt-polymer

I'm in dead end doing my own version of this [GWT-Polymer project hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer). Its fully working in the IDE, but at devsever it throws following error.

[image: Error image pasted inline]

```
if (src != null && !canCast(src, dstId)) {
  throw new ClassCastException();
}
```

canCast() returns **false**, because core-drawer-panel is not a JavaString *(look debug image)*, its HTML. Core-draw-panel can be found in Polymer GitHub.

So what i should do?
Version info:

- Polymer 0.5
- GWT 2.7
- JAVA 7

Comment: What are the compilation parameters you are using ?

Comment: I only have added -optimize 9 parameter. Others go by default [parameters](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT-Polymer uses a new feature in GWT called [JsInterop](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tir74SB-ZWrs-gQ8w-lOEV3oMY6u6lF2MmNivDEihZ4/edit), so I think the error you are getting is because you are not using the compiler flag to enable it.

Try to add to your compiler the option:

```
-XjsInteropMode JS
```

BTW, gwt-polymer is using gwt-2.8.0-SNAPSHOT which have last features, so probably you have to depend in your project on the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, your tips helped me to partially fix the problem and i finally got i work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what else did you do for make it work?